# How to avoid context objects and designing "UI states"

Tags: c++, state, ui, content-management

Note: I'm using Dear IMGUI, OpenGL and C++.

I have a UI, it has two "modes" one where it records and displays images and information about a recording device (IE camera) and another where it can read images and display them in from a certain format. The two "modes" share post processing functionality, in the sense there is a image processing algorithm run over both images that is exactly the same.  The parameters are changed in the same way across both "modes"

We will call the first mode acquisition mode, and the second display mode.

Previously, I required the UI to start in acquisition mode to get to any other mode.  This was easier to program at first, and originally made sense because it was the *only* mode present, but required the physical recording device to actually be connected in some way to one's computer.

This started to become a headache. I've encountered many scenarios where I only need the second mode, or where the first mode won't work for what ever reason, and I don't want to connect to said recording device.

Now I want the UI to start in a "modeless" start state, the default mode, where I then select whether I want to connect to another device or I want to display pre-recorded imagery. I also want to be able to switch back and forth with out restarting the whole program.

This need to switch between the two modes has some odd implications.  There's a whole set of "context" state required for each.  For example, in the acquisition mode, I don't want to go through the song and dance of connecting to a camera again and setting up all the associated state unless the user explicitly decides to connect to a different camera.  So somehow I need to save this information.  Similarly in display mode, I have a directory saved based on where the pre-recorded imagery was found, I don't want to have to reset that every mode switch. I also have threads that are used for messaging that have to be managed, and either destroyed or paused for each state.

This seems to call for separate "context" objects for each mode, but my understanding is that context objects should be avoided, as they lead to mangled classes of loosely cohesive state, and become garbage bins for state variables. Is there a way to avoid this pattern?

Comment: The argument against "context object" is the same as the argument against global state: it's not global state in itself that's the problem, it's the lack of an explicit, well defined access policy and no clear division of responsibility that turns it all into a garbage bin. A question: after you load this data, can you just pass parts of it to individual components, distributing responsibilities? I.e., does this change have a limited impact? Or does it affect how most of your *other code* (that's not concerned with context switching) stores and accesses state (you have to refactor it)?

Answer (score 3):

Well, *somewhere* one needs to buffer things like the camera connection and the associated state, or the information about the last used directories, that is pretty obvious. So at least there is something required which works *like* a context object.

To my experience, context objects are not an anti-pattern per se. However, they have a certain risk to become an issue when they have a vague name like "ContextObject", and one allows them to become a global "catch-all" container, putting all kind of state data into them with a mindset of "just-in-case", without a clear strategy of what goes in there and what not.

The alternative is to create **clear, well-named abstractions**, with deliberately chosen names and deliberately chosen responsibilities. For example,

- For your "acquisition mode", there could be a **Camera** class, which buffers the last  connection and required camera state internally (maybe on-demand, with lazy initialization, if this makes sense). If it is necessary to remember the latest active camera object, or maybe several ones, then there could be a second object required, something like a **CameraProvider**, or "CameraDesk", for managing exactly which camera objects with initialized state are currently available
- For the display mode, one may name provide something like **Galery** or **ImageStorage** and let it manage the latest state about those directories or images.
- For message threads, one may introduce a context object like **MessageThreadPool**.

<sub>(Since I write this from a 30000 feet view of your system, I am pretty sure you will need some different abstractions for the real thing, but I guess you get the idea).</sub>

So don't stay away from context objects just "because in some text book is written they are an anti pattern". When you create such objects carefully, with well chosen names and responsibilities, it is perfectly possible to keep such a system readable, maintainable and evolvable.